# Synchronuns call function one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call function one by one in which First function is completed then after second function is called. But here my problem is all 3 function call at a same time.

**JAVASCRIPT Code**

```
function func() {
    foo();
    bar();
    baz();
}


function foo(){
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("foo"); }, 3000);
    //alert("foo");
}

function bar(){
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("bar"); }, 3000);
//alert("bar");
}

function baz(){
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("baz"); }, 3000);
//alert("baz");
}

func();
```

**Expeted Output**

First call foo() then bar() and last baz();

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8hnf3Lja/1/)**

Comment: Look in to promises. Also, an example of your actual code may help here, as there may be a better pattern you can follow

Comment: of course because the timer will be started at the same time.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy But I called function one by one.

Comment: `setTimeout` will works Async,Even if you are calling sync.

Comment: @SankarRaj How can I achieve my goal to call synchronous function without `setTimeout`  function

Comment: @Sadikhasan check out my answer

Comment: repeated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are likely better options, and this option gets messy quickly, you can pass the next function in as a parameter.

Be careful with brackets `()` in this scenario.

```js
function func() {
  foo(function() {
    bar(function() {
      baz();
    })
  })
}

function foo(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("foo");
    if (callback != null) callback();
  }, 3000);
}

function bar(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("bar");
    if (callback != null) callback();
  }, 3000);
}

function baz(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("baz");
    if (callback != null) callback();
  }, 3000);
}

func()
```

Comment: Thanks for help. One question is without `setTimeout` Can I call synchronunsly function.

Comment: If you don't have any async code, then they will always run in sequence (synchronously).  I'm guessing you have an ajax call or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```js
function func() {
  foo();
}

var timer;

function foo() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("foo");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("bar");
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("baz");
      }, 3000);
    }, 3000);
  }, 3000);
  //alert("foo");
  console.log('comes first');
}


func();
```

Comment: Thanks for Help. My issue is I want to call function one by one without timeout. In first function I do some code after that execution I need to call second function. Is it possible?

Comment: do you need time interval while calling functions or not?

Comment: No i not need to time interval while calling function

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. Use generator functions.

NOTE: This `run` function is grabbed from [awync](https://github.com/tlghn/awync) and simplfilized .

```js
const GF = function*(){};
GF.constructor.prototype.run = function(cb){
  run(this, cb);
};
function run(genFunc, complete) {

    var rootObj = genFunc();

    function exit(result) {
        if(typeof complete === 'function'){
          complete(result, rootObj);
        }
    }

    function processYieldResult(yielded, genObj, prev, next) {

        if(yielded.done){

            if(genObj.cb) {
                return genObj.cb(prev);
            }

            if(genObj === rootObj){
                return exit(prev);
            }

            return;
        }

        if(yielded.value instanceof Promise){
            return yielded.value.then(
                function (result) {
                    setTimeout(next, 0, result);
                },
                function (err) {
                    if(!(err instanceof Error)){
                        err = new Error(err);
                    }
                    setTimeout(next, 0, err);
                }
            );
        }


        next(yielded.value);
    }

    function doRun(genObj, cb, prevResult) {
        genObj.cb = cb;
        function next(prev) {

            if(prev instanceof Error){
                return exit(prev);
            }

            var yielded;
            try{
                yielded = genObj.next(prev);
            }catch (err){
                return exit(err);
            }

            processYieldResult(yielded, genObj, prev, next);
        }
        if(!prevResult){
            next();
        } else {
            processYieldResult(prevResult, genObj, void 0, next);
        }
    }

    return doRun(rootObj);
}




function foo(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("foo"); resolve(); }, 1000);
  });
}

function bar(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("bar"); resolve(); }, 1000);
  });
}

function baz(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("baz"); resolve(); }, 1000);
  });
}

function *func() {
  yield foo();
  yield bar();
  yield baz();
}

func.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use promise for asynchronuns calls, but if you just want to call a function after another then you can do like below

```
 function foo(){
    //do your stuff in foo
    bar()
  }

 function bar(){
    //do your stuff in bar
    baz()
  }

 function baz(){
   //do your stuff in baz
  }
 foo();
```

Remember this will only call one function in other function. It will not work in case of asynchronous functions.

If you are looking for asynchronous calls then you have to use promises like below.

```
 var foo = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
        window.setTimeout(
            function() {
                resolve('hello');
            }, 1000);
     }
  );

 foo.then(
    function(val) {
       //do your stuff
       bar();
    })

 function bar(){
   //do your stuff
  }
```

You can follow this for n number of functions.